# dateadd function is not working in Hibbernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I want to get previous days data from my database and for that I have added a `DATE_ADD` function in my hibernate query using MySQL Database but I am getting error while running the query and here the query is:

```
select columnname 
from tablename 
where columnname = DATE_ADD(day,-1,getDate())
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple to call a function **if your function is returning a `string or varchar` value**.

`session.createSQLQuery("select my_fn(:param1)")`

Where **my_fn** is the name of your function with parameter **param1**.